# How to prevent an array from concatenating in a Semantic-UI table

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, html-table, semantic-ui

I am passing through a json data (as an array) to a semantic-ui table, and as a result I am seeing that array displayed concatenated as a single string instead of being comma-separated.

As you can see in the code below, the 6th line from the bottom has three items in an array concatenated as one string. In the console, however, I can see that they are three separate strings as marked by double quotation marks for each, delimited by new lines.

```
<table class="ui table">
<thead class="">
<tr class="">
<th class="">Name</th>
<th class="">Approval Rating</th>
<th class="">Review Count</th>
<th class="">Cuisine</th>
<th class="">Price Range</th>
<th class="">Address</th></tr></thead>
<tbody class="">
<tr class="">
<td class="">Arba</td>
<td class="">100</td>
<td class="">8</td>
<td class="">MediterraneanKosherMoroccan</td>
<td class="">-</td>
<td class="">472 Columbus Ave, New York, NY 10024</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How would you fix this issue so that it appears as the array it originally was? Or a way around this perhaps without using extra cells/lists? I am using the react semantic-ui via npm and its Table component.